# Windows 2008 R2 stand-alone: Change of hashing algorithm for user passwords

Tags: passwords, windows-server-2008-r2, hashing

On a Windows 2008 R2 machine, which is not part of an AD-environment, the local account passwords are stored using unsalted MD4 hashes. Is it possible, to

1. Change the hashing algorithm and
2. enable salting?

**UPDATE 1:**

I found a setting in gpedit.msc: Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Security Options > System cryptography: Use FIPS compliant algorithms for encryption.

According to [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811833/system-cryptography-use-fips-compliant-algorithms-for-encryption-hashi) this however does not seem to affect the hashing algorithm applied to user passwords.

Answer (score -1):

No, You are not allowed to change Hashing Algorithm in server 2008

Comment: Can you provide a citation for this?

Comment: @serverAdmin123 this answer without references or sources does not help.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/49zepq/active_directory_kerberos_salted_password_hashes/